# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] missing

Tags: php

I want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in my site but i get the following:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER
```

I have tried printing `$_SERVER`. This outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_HOST] => 192.168.1.10
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.1.10 Port 80
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
    [SERVER_NAME] => 192.168.1.10
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.1.10
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 192.168.1.77
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/sandeep/test/hash.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 53851
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /sandeep/test/hash.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /sandeep/test/hash.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /sandeep/test/hash.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1347365919
)
```

Can anyone help me to find `HTTP_REFERER` or suggest an alternative to `HTTP_REFERER`?

Comment: You have NOT guaranted that client will send http referer. If its not provided just dont work with it.

Comment: thanks for replay
is there any alternative for get previous site name ?

Comment: No. Referer can be also spoofed.

Comment: @ZaffyReally?? Can you explain the procedure!!

Comment: You can always use REMOTE_ADDR. I believe it is guaranteed to have the IP address of the computer that is requesting the file from your server. None of the other $_SERVER variables have worked reliably for me. HTTP_REFERER is guaranteed to work on your own server, if you have not suppressed it, so lack of HTTP_REFERER shows that the reference is from outside of your server.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER not reliable. but if you want to use then you can with

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){}

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 39):

When a web browser moves from one website to another and between pages of a website, it can optionally pass the URL it came from. This is called the HTTP_REFERER, So if you don't redirect from one page to another it might be missing

If the HTTP_REFERER has been set then it will be displayed. If it is not then you won't see anything. If it's not set and you have error reporting set to show notices, you'll see an error like this instead:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /path/to/filename.php
```

To prevent this error when notices are on (I always develop with notices on), you can do this:

```
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   }
```

**OR**

```
 echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

It can be useful to use the HTTP_REFERER variable for logging etc purposes using the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] superglobal variable. However it is important to know it's not always set so if you program with notices on then you'll need to allow for this in your code

Comment: Or now even `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']??''`

Answer (score 11):

Referer is not a [compulsory header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). It may or may not be there or could be modified/fictitious. Rely on it at your own risk. Anyways, you should wrap your call so you do not get an undefined index error:

```
$server = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
```

Comment: "compulsory" does not occur in the link "compulsory header". What remote identifiers are present in the compulsory headers that could be used instead of HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: @David Spector If you need identity you should be implementing user authentication

Comment: Agree that identity requires user auth. However, identifying malicious users and bots cannot be done with user auth, and in general, user auth keeps the public from viewing one's website. In my case, I want my websites to be viewed.

Answer (score 9):

You can and should never assume that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will be present.

If you control the previous page, you can pass the URL as a parameter `"site.com/page2.php?prevUrl=".urlencode("site.com/page1.php")`.

If you don't control the page, then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4):

*SOLUTION*

As stated by others very well, HTTP_REFERER is set by the local machine of the user, specifically the browser, which means it's not reliable for security.  However, this still is entirely the way in which *Google Analytics* monitors where you're getting your visitors from, so, it can actually be useful to check, exclude, include, etc..

*If you think you should see an HTTP_REFERER and do not, add this to your PHP code, preferably at the top:*

```
ini_set('session.referer_check', 'TRUE');
```

A more appropriate long-term solution, of course, is to actually update your php.ini or equivalent file.  This is a nice and quick way of verifying, though.

*TESTING*

Run `print($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` on your site, go to google.com, inspect some text, edit it to be `<a href="https://example.com">LINK!</a>`, apply the change, then click the link.  If it works, all is well and running precisely!

But maybe $_SERVER is wrong, or the test above says it's broken.  Update your page with this, and then test again...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("REFER!" + document.referrer + "|" + location.referrer + "|");
</script>
```

*USES*

**I use HTTP REFERER to block spam sites in GoogleAnalytics.**  Below is a graph focusing on one particular website's referrals.  From 0 to 44 in one day, it wasn't caused by real users.  It was caused by a botted site trying to get my attention to buy their services.  But it just started because php.ini was updated to ignore the referer, which meant these spam, junk garbage sites were not getting their appropriate ERROR 403, "Access Denied."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirectHome($theMsg, $url = null, $seconds = 3) {
    if ($url === null) {
        $url  = 'index.php';
        $link = 'Homepage';
    } else {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== '') {
            $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $link = 'Previous Page';
        } else {
            $url = 'index.php';
            $link = 'Homepage';
        }
    }
    echo $theMsg;
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>You Will Be Redirected to $link After $seconds Seconds.</div>";
    header("refresh:$seconds;url=$url");
    exit();
}
```