# Error in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

i just tried

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

but it returned an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in C:\Program Files\....
```

What is the problem an why is it showing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because **HTTP_REFERER** is not set
you can try

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
else
    echo 'HTTP_REFERER in not set';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
                                     : "Referer not set";
```

Possible Duplicate of [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server error reporting level is too sensitive (E_ALL) and there actually is no referrer.