# How can I use $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']; in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I tried using the same code that I have for a platform that does not use laravel but it gives me an error: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if($referrer === 'http://example.example.info/prueba/')
{
 //continue
}
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836236/error-in-serverhttp-referer

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713409/laravel-5-4-get-referer

Comment: there doesn't have to be a referer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get HTTP_REFERER in laravel with `Request::server()`;

`Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')`

Refer : https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server

Comment: I am trying to use `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')`
 but only receives null.
I need that if a user comes from a specific URL I can access the web and see my content

Comment: I treid it and it's giving me url.
    `public function index(Request $request)
    {
        echo $request->server('HTTP_REFERER');
   }`