# LoginIn check using Session PHP

Tags: php, session

I am applying check on Login page that whenever user clicks on login page their previous location gets saved into session like ,

```
    $_SESSION['httpReferer']=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

now  if the user clicks on login page more than one time i have to store the location just for the first time bacause after logging in i am redirecting user back to the page it came from using the location  have saved in $_SESSION['httpReferer']. The problem is I have tried empty() , i have tried isset() i have tried null() on $_SESSION['htttpReferr'] but nothing is working .It keeps on storing the location again and again in session .The check is not working.

```
    if( empty($_SESSION['httpReferer']))
    {
    $_SESSION['httpReferer']=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
```

Please a little help.Thanks !

Comment: have you put `session_start();` in starting of the page?? see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing

Comment: yes I have put session_start(); in the starting

Comment: have you tried initializing the `$_SESSION['httpReferer']` if it's not set, and comparing to the initialized value ? 
`if (!isset($_SESSION['httpReferer']))
{
 $_SESSION['httpReferer'] = 'new';
}
if ( $_SESSION['httpReferer'] == 'new' )
{
 $_SESSION['httpReferer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}`

also ... make sure you unset the `$_SESSION['httpReferer']` before trying this ...