# Yii2 back to previous page after validate error

Tags: url, yii2, referrer

I'm using Yii2 as my framework, but I have a problem with Yii::$app->request->referrer

In my case I enter URL : http://myframework.local/app/view?id=10 and it show me the data by id 10 from database, when I edit the URL : http://myframework.local/app/view?id=1001 it should error because there's no id 1001 in database.
is there any way I go back to the previous page which has URL : http://myframework.local/app/view?id=10

because Yii::$app->request->referrer won't work in my case.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you editing the url in the address bar on your browser or are you doing it in the code?

Comment: I edit the url in the address bar..

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12369682/57091) out. It is not a Yii issue, I guess.