# Displaying HTTP referrer

Tags: php, html, http

I tried a code from another question and it didn't work.

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
echo "Referrer = $ref";
?>
```

What is wrong with code? All it displays is "Referrer =       "

Comment: What happened with your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104390/storing-http-referrer-as-a-variable/ under a different username ?

Comment: create a link on your question ( you can remove it after) to the php file with the code above.

Comment: Did you go to this page from another one ? If it's the first page you visit, it's absolutely normal that the referer is empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked from another link `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` can initialize.

Comment: are you sure you are clicking from another link?

Comment: 100% positive I pasted into web.skype.com and I pasted into gmail

Comment: please use this codes to show you errors. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);`