# PHP - How to make sure requests are coming from my website?

Tags: php, http, http-referer

I have a website (https://example.com/) that has a form on it.  The form uses POST to connect to another website (https://app.example.com/).  The other website (https://app.example.com/), connects to a mysql database.  I am getting fake inputs on the database.  All of the fake inputs do not have referers.  I added this code to the other website (https://app.example.com/) to fix this problem,

```
$allowed_host = 'example.com';
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$hacker_page = 'https://app.example.com/hacker.php';
$host = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_HOST);
if($referer == ''){
    header("Location: $hacker_page");
}
if(!(substr($host, 0 - strlen($allowed_host)) == $allowed_host)) {
    header("Location: $hacker_page");
}
```

but I am still getting fake inputs...

Comment: Do you have any way to make use of a token to validate the authenticity of the request?

Comment: That is what the $allowed_host is.

Comment: Like a cookie??

Comment: something that doesn't rely on the referer. Could be a secret key passed in the request.

Comment: Like a hidden field on the form?

Comment: Yes I do, it is a hidden field on the main domain's form.

Comment: Similar but something that couldn't be accessed by a user.

Comment: Like what?  I really would like not to use cookies...

Comment: Anything. 
For example, [a cryptographically secure random string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18890309/2263631), `48071997cf20790e33b13dcc256abcdca6bd4a5d139577de65d5cc9b3a07` is the token that is passed and you validate every request to ensure it has a valid token on the other end. If it does, proceed. If not, 403. Ideally the token should have a life time so it expires.

Comment: How to pass the token without the user seeing it?

Comment: That depends on how the request is being made, if the request is being made by the server then you just pass it in the params and they'd never see it. Client side would make it impossible, to my knowledge.

Comment: It is a pure HTML form being sent to a secondary domain.

Comment: Then the only thing I can suggest is to make the token only work for one request and even then, give it an expiry. But that too isn't 100%.

Comment: So no http-headers?

Comment: ['*The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.*'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369682/2263631) - Not the referer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I might try using cookies...  It is wordpress, so IDK how to use cookies.

Comment: Don't use WordPress but this might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/setting-custom-cookies-in-wordpress

Comment: Captcha best easy method

Comment: I ended up using captcha.