# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working in https

Tags: php, http, https

I am using in my php `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it was working in fine. when i am using `http://www.example.com/index.php` but it i am using `https://www.example.com/index.php` not working. Can anyone please tell how can overcome this issue?

Comment: you found the reply here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: _"it was working in fine"_ - no, it never was. You might just not have encountered or noticed any of the usual problems yet. The HTTP referrer is not _reliable_, and should not be used for any kind of important decision ever.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it ?